# Connecting to open networks using nmcli Wi-Fi network could not be found

Tags: wifi, network-interface, networkmanager, nmcli, armbian

I have an an orange pi zero running armbian I am having problem connecting to open networks using nmcli. I can very well connect to my home "WPA1 WPA2" secured network with no issue at all. Here is to list the network:

```
# nmcli device wifi list

IN-USE  BSSID              SSID               MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY

        XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  MyNetwork          Infra  7     405 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
```

I use the following command to connect to it and it works perfect:

```
# nmcli device wifi con MyNetwork password 'mypassword'

Connection 'MyNetwork' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/48)
```

Now if I turn my android phone to a hotspot with no password, the nmcli can not connect to it. Here is how the nmcli sees the open hotspot (as you can see there are no security set):

```
# nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID               MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
        XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  MyNetwork          Infra  7     405 Mbit/s  97      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
        XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  OpenNetwork        Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  94      ▂▄▆█  --
```

My assumption is that I should just use the same command I used to connect to my secure WiFi, but omit the password part...but for some reason I get the following error:

```
# nmcli device wifi con OpenNetwork
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.
```

I tried this with some other open networks, I get the same error. Is there something that I am missing? is the a driver issue? or is there some settings that I need to change/enable for nmcli to support open networks?

Answer (score 0):

```
root@imx6sxsabresd:~# sudo nmcli --ask dev wifi connect test6

Device 'wlan0' successfully activated with '2b7c9262-6953-4b2b-8cf1-cc5db544c666'.

root@imx6sxsabresd:~# iwconfig wlan0

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"test6"

Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 52:D2:F5:2E:2B:EA
      Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

root@imx6sxsabresd:~#
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).